# How to parse strings using elasticsearh

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use ElasticSearch to separate tokens in a string ,lets say I have a string I want to extract a name from:

```
John Smith had a little lamb
```

My idea is to create several versions of it, search them on a name index and get the one with the biggest score:

```
John
John Smith
John Smith had
....
```

What's the best way to do that with ElasticSearch?

Edit:
I want something like this:

```
//this combination is not right, gives me a low score
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        { "match" : { "name" : "John" } },
      ],
    }
  }
}
//this combination is right, gives me a high score
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        { "match" : { "name" : "John" } },
        { "match" : { "name" : "Smith" } },
      ],
    }
  }
}
//this one also gives me a low score, stop searching here
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        { "match" : { "name" : "John" } },
        { "match" : { "name" : "Smith" } },
        { "match" : { "name" : "had" } },
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

How I can do this process in just one query?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Im running a bool query for each possible sentence, i was wondering if I can do the whole thing on a single query

Comment: Can you include the mapping of your index? Can you include the bool query you tried in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear how you would extract a name from this document. Surely not something elasticsearch can do and will need to come from some logic...
Is the name categorize by words which always start with upper case letter ? If so use whitespace analyzer as english analyzer would lowercase and stem those terms

Regarding score, I'm not clear how this will help you... What score higher is terms which are least common - lamb might be less common in your index than term John or Smith but "little" might be more common, so I don't know how this will help you know that name is "John Smith"
Or are you saying you are looking for set of two tokens/words...

Maybe question here is around clarifying what you want to achieve and then you can check how ES can do it